# Did the United States colonize California?

Tags: united-states, historiography, colonization, colonial-america, california

Upper California was a province of Mexico from the 1820s to the 1840s (sometimes unified with Lower California). Near the end of this period it was overrun with Anglo-American men that lived apart from Spanish-speaking society. Thomas O. Larkin was the U.S. consul and President's secret agent in the capital, Monterey. When the Treaty of Guadalupe Hidalgo was signed, California became a U.S. territory. It then experienced a Gold Rush and in 1850 it became one of the United States.

Was the settlement by the United States of California considered a "colonization" by historians?

Comment: Probably. As always, it will depend on how you define the your terms,
 but using the Oxford dictionary definition of ["colonize"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colonize) then the answer would seem to be yes. And that colonisation followed earlier Spanish and Russian efforts to colonise California.

Comment: Tough to resolve; if you don't define what "colonize" means, the question might be opinion related; if you do, the question is probably trivial.   I'm going to abstain and hope that someone provides an answer with the definition and a justification for applying that definition.

Comment: I reworded the question in a way that can be answered objectively and vote to reopen.